# Share link to social media from Phone

Tags: c#, facebook, hyperlink, windows-phone, share

i am developing an app in wp7, which gives you the ability to post on social networks, the song you are listening with name, description and link!

The app is writen with # for Windows Phone and it use

```
ShareLinkTask shareLinkTask = new ShareLinkTask();
```

to post the link of song from YouTube!

The format of post is like:

```
Link = SONGLINK
```

```
Message = Listening now: SONGNAME from APP(APPLINK)
```

The problem is that when i post to facebook the SONGLINK does not have a preview, so is displayed like APPLINK in text-blue-hyperlink with border!
I think is like facebook gets the link but not loads the preview...

I also tried to post facebook via the Facebook app (Microsoft's) and i got the same result, so the app has not problem but the facebook service?

Problem it seems to be from facebook as when i am working with twitter i have the preview with the same code sample!

So any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem it seem to be solved from facebook after some days, it seems that this happend due maintence of the facebook page.